# Currency.getSymbol() gives "US$" and "$" with different devices

Tags: java, android, locale, currency-formatting

While Initializing Currency, I set locale ad locale.US
Currency.getInstance(Locale.US), but getSymbol() gives "US$" and "$ on different devices. getSymbol() gives "$" on samsung, but gives "US$" on moto. How to solve this.

Comment: Javadoc of [`Currency.getSymbol()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol()): Gets the symbol of this currency for the default DISPLAY locale.For example, for the US Dollar, the symbol is "$" if the defaultlocale is the US, while for other locales it may be "US$". If no symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217 currency code is returned.

Comment: Try `Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getSymbol(Locale.US)`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks it worked. Passing locale on getSymbol(Locale.US) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the javadoc of [`Currency.getSymbol()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol())

> Gets the symbol of this currency for the default [`DISPLAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.Category.html#DISPLAY) locale. For example, for the US Dollar, the symbol is "$" if the default locale is the US, while for other locales it may be "US$". If no symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217 currency code is returned.
>
> If the default  [`DISPLAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.Category.html#DISPLAY) locale contains "rg" (region override) Unicode extension, the symbol returned from this method reflects the value specified with that extension.
>
> This is equivalent to calling [`getSymbol(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol(java.util.Locale)).

This describes the reason why you sometimes see "US$" and sometimes just "$".

If you want to get reproducible results use

```
Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getSymbol(Locale.US).
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin -

`android.icu.util.Currency.getInstance("currency_code").getName(Locale.getDefault(),android.icu.util.Currency.NARROW_SYMBOL_NAME,null)`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/util/Currency#narrow_symbol_name

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/util/Currency#getname